# how to check if overflow:hidden html class has cut out from view content using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="scrollable" style="overflow: hidden"> </div>

$(function() {
    if($(".scrollable").hasElementsInsideItThatAreCutOffByOverflowHidden == false){
    $(".scrollable").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true });
    }   
}


<a onClick="isHidingMyStuff"> check if your stuff is hidden <a>
```

this doesnt work

Comment: could you make your function more work-friendly?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: he means the word starting with "s" and ending in "it".

Comment: Wrongly closed, this isn't about detecting display, its about detecting if the height of elements inside the overflow controlled area exceed the parent height, hence triggering scrolls.

Comment: voted for re-opening because the OP is asking for scroll-hidding.. whether or not there is more content hidden due to `overflow:hidden` **not** `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`

Comment: I don't know any dedicated solution, but maybe you could measure the element width and cache it to a variable. Then disable the height or width property (the one that matters or both)(or set it to auto) and measure it again. Now you can undo your css changes and check measures. If the new was greater, you have hidden content. If the question opens again I'll post as answer

Comment: Here is my solution http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/ApZP2/ Will post as answer if/when the it gets re-opened..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We wrap the contents in a div so we can get a height from it and compare to the `.scrollable` height (*which is not scrollable..*)

```
function isHidingMyStuff(){
    var $s = $('.scrollable');
    
    $s.wrapInner('<div />'); // wrap inner contents
    var hidden = $s.height() < $s.children('div').height();
    
    $s.children('div').replaceWith( $s.children('div').html() ); //unwrap
    
    return hidden;
}
```

**demo :**

```js
function isHidingMyShit() {
  var $s = $('.scrollable');

  $s.wrapInner('<div />'); // wrap inner contents
  var hidden = $s.height() < $s.children('div').height();

  $s.children('div').replaceWith($s.children('div').html()); //unwrap

  return hidden;
}
```

```css
.scrollable {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollable" style="overflow:hidden;">
  test testtest testtest testtest<br /> testtest testtest testtest testtest<br /> testtest testtest testtest testtest<br /> testtest test TOST
</div>


<a href="#" onClick="alert(isHidingMyShit())"> check if your shit is hidden <a>
```

Comment: yup, that's the way to go, +1

Comment: Why don't u simply use `.unwrap()`?

Comment: @meo, because `unwrap` removes the parent element. In this case i want to remove the inner wrapper and there is no way to go deeper than that.

Comment: oh ok. But does your replaceWith not replace all div's that are inside .scrollable ?

Comment: @meo, the `filter` finds the immediate children (*one level down*), and the only one that exists is the one i put there with `wrapInner`.

Answer (score 4):

Using javascript and if div has id then

```
<div id="scrollable"  class="scrollable" style="overflow: hidden"> </div>


function check_string_is_hidden_due_to_overflow(div_id) {
        var s_h = document.getElementById(div_id).scrollHeight;
        var c_h = document.getElementById(div_id).clientHeight;
        if(s_h != c_h) {
            return true; // Means some content is hidden due to overflow hidden
        } else {
            return false; // Whole content is displayed.
        }

}
```

check_string_is_hidden_due_to_overflow("scrollable");